# When I try to melt my data frame with mixed data types, I get NAs. How can I best resolve this?

Tags: r, reshape

## My goal and context

I have a data frame in R that I want to melt using the reshape2 library. There are two reasons.

1. I want to plot the score for each user for each question in a bar chart using ggplot.
2. I want to put this data into Excel so I can see, per user, their sentiment, score, and mixed for motivation, attitudeBefore, etc. My intention was to use melt, then cast to put the data into wide format for easy Excel importing.

## My problem

When I try to run melt, I get a warning and end up with NAs in my resulting molten data frame.

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0.148024, 0.244452, -0.00421,  :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

And I end up with a ton of NAs in my resulting melted data frame. I think it's because I'm using both characters and numerics in the same column.

## My questions

I have two questions as a result.

**Question 1: Is there a workaround for this in R?**

**Question 2: Is there a better way for me to structure my data to avoid this problem?**

## Code

Here's my code for creating the data frame.

```
words <- data.frame(read.delim("sentiments-test-subset-no-text.txt", header=FALSE))
names(words) <- c("level", "question", "user", "sentiment", "score", "mixed")
words$user <- as.factor(words$user)
words.m <- melt(words, id.vars=c("user", "level"), measure.vars=c("sentiment", "score",     "mixed"))
```

I'm pretty new to reshape and melt but I *think* that's what I want in the last line.

## Data

The data in human-readable format looks like this.

```
experimental    motivated   1   positive    0.148024    0
experimental    motivated   2   positive    0.244452    0
experimental    motivated   3   negative       -0.004210    0
experimental    motivated   4   unknown         0.000000    0
experimental    attitudeBefore  1   negative       -0.241500    0
experimental    attitudeBefore  2   neutral         0.000000    0
experimental    attitudeBefore  3   neutral         0.000000    0
experimental    attitudeBefore  4   unknown         0.000000    0
```

## dput dump

dput below.

```
structure(list(level = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = "experimental", class = "factor"), question = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("attitudeBefore", "motivated"
), class = "factor"), user = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
sentiment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("negative", 
"neutral", "positive", "unknown"), class = "factor"), score = c(0.148024, 
0.244452, -0.00421, 0, -0.2415, 0, 0, 0), mixed = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("level", "question", 
"user", "sentiment", "score", "mixed"), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why exactly you want to do this. You are attempting to create a data frame with a column with _multiple data types_. The resulting value column will hold numerical values as well as characters (positive, negative, etc). Each column of a data frame must contain a single atomic type.

Comment: @joran Call it old habits perhaps. I am used to keeping most of my data in a single data frame and simply selecting the data I need to plot when I need it. I am new to melt(). Do you recommend I create separate data frames, one for each response variable? Also, in my Goal and Context, I describe how I want to compare my data side-by-side in Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you might simply be using the wrong library. 
`reshape` and `reshape2` are not the same thing.

```
library(reshape2)
words.m <- melt(words, id.vars=c("user", "level"), measure.vars=c("sentiment", "score",     "mixed"))
# no problem

detach(package:reshape2)

# using reshape instead of reshape2
library(reshape)
words.m <- melt(words, id.vars=c("user", "level"), measure.vars=c("sentiment", "score",     "mixed"))
# Warning messages:
# 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  :
#   invalid factor level, NAs generated
# 2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L,  :
#   invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

if `reshape2` is not available on your system, you can install it from CRAN

```
 install.packages("reshape2")
```

Comment: Can you describe what the difference between reshape and reshape2 are, and when I should be using one vs. the other?

Comment: @Irwin you should use `reshape2` - it replaced `reshape`. You can read [a note from the author](https://github.com/hadley/reshape) that talks about some differences .